# using aggregation with rmongodb package

Tags: r, mongodb

I am a newbie to both R and MongoDB and I am trying to implement aggregation on the following dataset:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5569fdb796f77d81b8aacf45"),
  "PLAYER NAME" : "DA Warner",
  "TEAM" : "SRH",
  "RUNS" : 562.0,
  "MATCH" : "14",
  "HS" : "91",
  "AVE" : 43.23,
  "SR" : 156.54,
  "100'S" : "0",
  "50'S" : 7.0
}

/* 2 */
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5569fdb796f77d81b8aacf46"),
  "PLAYER NAME" : "Ajinkya Rahane",
  "TEAM" : "RR",
  "RUNS" : 540.0,
  "MATCH" : "14",
  "HS" : "91*",
  "AVE" : 49.8,
  "SR" : 133.15,
  "100'S" : "0",
  "50'S" : 4.0
}
```

by using this piece of code:

```
pipe <- mongo.bson.from.JSON('{"group":{"_id":"$TEAM", "total_runs":{"$sum":"$RUNS"}}}')
cmd_list <- list(pipe)
result <- mongo.aggregation(mongo, "test.IPL_Most_Runs" , cmd_list)
```

However I am getting an error saying BSON is not valid.
Can anybody please help me with the R code regarding this.??

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [**RMongo package**](https://github.com/tc/RMongo) which lets you query MongoDB databases. For instance, you can use the [**`dbAggregate()`**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RMongo/RMongo.pdf) method to perform a MongoDB aggregate query as follows:

```
mongo <- mongoDbConnect("test")
output <- dbAggregate(mongo, "IPL_Most_Runs", c(' { "$group" : { "_id" : "$baz", "total_runs":{ "$sum":"$RUNS"} } } ')
print(output)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.Could you also please help me out on how to convert a bson to a data.frame object.I have converted the bson to a list but the data frame is coming out to be horizontal.
CSK 1961 RCB 1509 MI 1860

Comment: I think this [**link**](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/rmongodb/docs/mongo.cursor.to.data.frame) might prove useful to you.